# How do I properly embed Cesium inside grid element

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, css-grid, cesiumjs

I'm attempting to control my Cesium container element with CSS Grid. But in Edge it seems to automatically zoom past the Earth if it is within the grid. It does not seem to happen if I use Chrome or even IE. What exactly is happening and how should I combat it? Basic code being used below. Can use https://codepen.io/rachelandrew/pen/XdZydB to plug it in:

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 40px;
}
.wrapper {
        display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, [col] 100% ) ;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, [row] auto  );
        background-color: #fff;
        color: #444;
    }
    .box {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 150%;

    }

    .a {
        grid-column: col / span 2;
        grid-row: row ;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="cesiumContainer" class="box a">A</div>
</div>
  <script src="https://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.55/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.55/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
```

EDIT: I did not notice at first, but I had overflow set to hidden. Removing that reveals that Edge seems to forever increase the element resize when using Cesium. I think it has something to do with

```
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, [col] 100% ) ;
```

EDIT 2: I ended up ditching the grid for my Cesium-related work. I never found a solution using the grid technology. Instead, I've implemented flex groups which don't seem to affect the rendering in the same way. I did keep a copy of my other framework in the hopes that I'll stumble on a solution, if I do I'll post an official answer unless someone beats me to it.